# Visual Studio Express 2015. Changes in form does not apply on debug

Tags: vb.net, windows, forms

I just had a really weird thing happening on the application I'm developing.
Everything was doing well until, suddenly, I can't do any change on my form.
If I modify something in my form, a button text for example, it appears with the new name in the designer but if I start the application it runs with the previous version of the text in the button. I tried modifying a lot of things, position, text, color, really messing up my design but when I start it I don't see any change...  I even tried to change things from the code (change button text on form load) but still no change... I try shutting down and restart the PC, no better luck...

I probably have touched something somewhere that cause this problem but I do not know what and this turns me nuts...

Other apps I made before are still running perfectly and running with new content if I edit their design form.

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot.
Vince

Comment: Is there a way for you to post a specific example? Questions do much better here when there is code or other visuals to look at.

Comment: make sure that you are changing the form you think you are

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for very late answer. I cannot give and post any specific example as this can happen at any time without warning and does not only affect forms (so, yes,I'm sure I'm working on the right form). I can just simply change a content like 'label1.text = "something"' and if I run the program the content of that label stays unchanged completely ignoring the changes made in code of form. The only solution I found is, when this happen, I stop working on that project and come back the next day and everything is fine...  Really wierd...